# QT Application Unexplainable crash with Sqlite INSERT function

Tags: c++, database, qt, sqlite

I'm doing calorie counter app. I'm new to QT and this error is way too hard to figure out. I've been thinking more than 3h and nothing.
here is the function which causes error

```
 bool MainWindow::saveDB()
{
    loading = true;
    QSqlQuery q(db);
    q.exec("DELETE FROM Food");
    q.prepare("INSERT INTO Food(id,Name,Carbohydrates,Fats,Proteins,Calories) VALUES(:id,:n,:c,:f,:p,:cal)");
        for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
                     q.bindValue(":n",ui->tableWidget->item(i,1)->text());
                     q.bindValue(":c",ui->tableWidget->item(i,2)->text().toInt());
                     q.bindValue(":f",ui->tableWidget->item(i,3)->text().toInt());
                     q.bindValue(":p",ui->tableWidget->item(i,4)->text().toInt());
                     q.bindValue(":cal",ui->tableWidget->item(i,5)->text().toInt());
                     q.bindValue(":id",ui->tableWidget->item(i,0)->text().toInt());
             if(!q.exec())
             {
                 qDebug() << q.lastError().text();
                 loading = false;
                 return false;
             }
        }
    loading = false;
    return true;
}
```

It is supposed to clear database and it does, and then insert values from tableWidget.

App Output

```
 The program has unexpectedly finished.
D:\Calc\build-CalcProto-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\CalcProto.exe crashed
```

db is my QSqlDatabase object.
Data is presented in tableWidget which has 6 columns, (id,Name,Carbohydrates,Fats,Proteins,Calories), qDebug doesnt show any message.I tried dozens of variations, it simply always crash.
There is also loading data function which works perfectly, so the database itself is fine. Update function works fine, but the INSERT always fails. No idea whats wrong. Could you please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Which line does the crash occur on?

Comment: Debugger doesnt provide that information, would be nice if it did

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, 1 more hour was necessary :D
"id" column in database has auto incrementation which collided with tableWidget data even if they were equal. Never try to INSERT data column that has autoincrementation on.